# How to avoid Heatmap layers in google maps stacking over each other

Tags: google-maps-api-3, slider, heatmap

I am trying to implement a HTML slider and attaching the slider value with the radius of the location's heatmap. As I increase the slider , the radius is increasing properly. But as I reduce it, instead of reducing, it is overlaying on the existing heatmap, Hence could not see any difference.

HTML Code

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
<style="text-align:center; font: 5px; padding-top: 0px;"> Choose the Time range </style>                              
<br><input type="range" min="1" max="24" value="0" class="slider" name="sder" form="form1" id="myRange" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"></div>
```

JS Code

```
var chenai = new google.maps.LatLng(13.051126, 80.195590);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: chenai,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  });

 function updateTextInput(val) {

        var testheatMapData = [
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(13.034603, 80.207509), weight: 20},
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(13.071126, 80.195590), weight: 15},
            {location: new google.maps.LatLng(13.025914, 80.156675), weight: 10}     ];

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatMapData,
          radius: val,
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);

}
```

Comment: I had no idea these 9 lines of code alone would display a map, a heatmap, a slider, and handle adjusting a radius with a slider.

Comment: I have added the code for display of the map as it is trivial. I have just added the code for slider as well.

Comment: No you haven't.

Comment: Now I have added both the HTML and the JS code @MrUpsidown

Comment: Please learn what is a [mcve] and try to provide one each time with your questions. You are creating the heatmap layer every time you change the slider. Instead use the heatmap `setOptions` method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the heatmap layer and
2. Update its radius in the update function called by the slider

```js
var map;
var heatmap;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.783, -122.445),
    zoom: 13
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var heatmapData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435)
  ];

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: heatmapData,
    radius: 10,
    map: map
  });
}

function updateTextInput(val) {

  heatmap.setOptions({
    radius: val
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<input type="range" min="1" max="24" value="10" class="slider" name="sder" form="form1" id="myRange" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=visualization" async defer></script>
```